# How to implement the value from redux store to tabBarBadge?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

So I have implemented the redux from my app and I can also access the value from the redux my problem is how can I implement the value from the redux to the specific screen even though im not opening the screen where I want the badge to be displayed.

```
navigation.setOptions({
       tabBarBadge:
         store.getState().notif.count === 0
           ? null
           : store.getState().notif.count,
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the badge where you define the screens instead of using `setOptions`:

```js
const count = useSelector(state => state.notif.count);

return (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Whatever"
      component={Whatever}
      options={{
        tabBarBadge: count
      }}
    />
    {/* ...other screens */}
  </Tab.Navigator>
);
```